# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I wrote the following code. When I try to run it as at the end of the file I get this stacktrace:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute do_something
```

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_something(self, some_parameter, next_parameter):
        if type(some_parameter) is not int:
            raise AttributeError("Some message")
        if type(next_parameter) is not int:
            raise AttributeError("Some message")


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent).__init__()

    def do_something(self, some_parameter, next_parameter):
        super(Parent).do_something(some_parameter, next_parameter)
        return some_parameter + next_parameter


object = Child()
object.do_something(2, 2)
```

How should I solve this and where did I the mistake in this simply inheritance sample?

Comment: I think you forgot the `self` parameter in `do_something` method in parent class.

Comment: None of your methods have a `self` parameter, and `super(Parent)` should be `super()`, and why on earth are you raising *AttributeError* if your type checks fail?

Comment: You're right I forgot to write this parameter but only in this sample in my code I did not forget about self parameter and it's still getting the same error. But thanks the same.

Comment: None of your `__init__` methods have `self` parameters.

Comment: I just added self param in the method definition and it's still not the reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're passing the wrong argument to `super`. If you're going to pass arguments at all, they need to be the *current* class and instance, not the parent class you're expecting to call. Or assuming you're using Python 3, you can skip the arguments completely and the compiler will make it work for you anyway. Calling `super` with one argument is allowed, but it returns an "unbound super object" which is almost never useful.

Change your calls to use one of these styles:

```
class Child(Parent):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()   # no arguments is almost always best in Python 3

   def do_something(self, some_parameter, next_parameter):
      super(Child, self).do_something(some_parameter, next_parameter) # name the current class
      return some_parameter + next_parameter
```

I'd also note that your type checks in `Parent.do_something` are rather awkward. Rather than `type(some_parameter) is not int`, use `isinstance(some_parameter, int)` (unless you deliberately want to exclude subtypes).

Comment: Great thanks for the answer. Is it better to use only super() or call it with the args SubClassName and self? What is more recommended?

Comment: If you only need to support Python 3, using the no-argument for is almost always best, because it's simpler and you don't need to change it if you rename the class. The two argument form is the only one that works in Python 2, so use it if you need backwards compatibility (this is getting much less important as Python 2 approaches its end of life).

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I am using Python 3.12.1 and ran into an issue where `super()` with no arguments does not work if you import a class from another file. It only works if you have the class definition on the same file, above your child class. I had to use the two-parameter version to get it to work when importing from another file.

Comment: @JuanR: I'm not sure when you'd be using `super` without it being *inside* of the class. The no-argument version only works in that context. If you're calling `super` on some other object, the two argument version works, but it's usually not a good idea to be bypassing the class's own methods in the first place.

Comment: @Blckknght sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant to say is that if you have your base class definition on another file, `super()` without arguments will not work, even if you import the class at the top. I confirmed this by commenting the base class on the separate file, commenting the import and pasting it directly above the child class. Only the `super()` with arguments works with separate files. It looks like the compiler doesn't like it. It was driving me nuts and I could not figure out why it wasn't working until I ran across this post and tried the one with parameters just for kicks.

Comment: @JuanR: That shouldn't be happening, inheritance (and `super`) should work the same regardless of where each type is defined. I'd guess there's something more complicated going on, that's throwing off the `super()` mechanics. Maybe your imported class uses a weird metaclass or something.

Comment: @Blckknght trust me, I was as surprised as you are. It's a very simple setup. Nothing crazy. I bet you can reproduce it yourself. I would submit a bug report but I just don't have the time right now.

Comment: @JuanR: I did test it, and it doesn't work as you say. I made a `Base` class in one file, imported that module, and made a `Derived` class that inherits from `base.Base`. In a method in `Derived`, I call `super()` to get at the same method in `Base`, and it works fine. If it doesn't work in your situation, there must be something else going on. Are you trying to inject a method into the derived class? The compiler can only make no-argument `super()` work for methods defined within a class.

Comment: @Blckknght nothing else going on. Simple example. By the way, I am running this on VS Code (Windows). That's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here. Firstly there was an indentation error for the parent `do_something` definition. This meant that it was defined as a function in and of itself, rather than being a method of the class `Parent`.

Secondly, class methods should usually have `self` as their first parameter, as when they are called, the object that they refer to is passed as the first variable.

Thirdly, when you call `super()` you do not need to specify what the super is, as that is inherent in the class definition for `Child`.

Below is a fixed version of your code which should perform as you expect.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def do_something(self, some_parameter, next_parameter):
        if type(some_parameter) is not int:
            raise AttributeError("Some message")
        if type(next_parameter) is not int:
            raise AttributeError("Some message")
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent).__init__()
    def do_something(self, some_parameter, next_parameter):
        super().do_something(some_parameter, next_parameter)
        return some_parameter + next_parameter

test = Child()
test.do_something(2, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks that's it :)

Comment: Just as an addition, it looks like the first `def __init__():` was doubly indented which may have caused the initial problem.